# How is the overflow flag not set after this addition?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, signed, twos-complement

I'm learning about x86 assembly(8086 to be more specific) and I'm confused about the concept of flags, I tried searching about it online and found this image :

[image]

According to the image , after the addition operation of the two 16 bit numbers, the OF flag is still clear at 0.

But I've learnt that if the MSB of the two numbers to be added is off (so a 0) and the MSB of the result is a 1, then overflow has occurred.

Link to the webpage I've learned this from : http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt

Can someone explain why the OF is still at 0 please?

Comment: That is wrong, assuming it is a 16 bit addition. Both `SF` and `OF` should be 1 (you can check in a debugger). `SF` is obviously 1 since the MSB is 1.

Comment: Ah so the image is wrong right?

Comment: Yes, wrong for 16-bit arithmetic. Very wrong, or taken (way) out of some other context.  It shows adding the same numbers, and subtracting them, yet the resulting sum and difference are the same number..

Comment: Adding two non-negative numbers and getting a negative is signed overflow; OF should be set.  The numeric result looks correct for addition, but the FLAGS are wrong.  The numeric result is pretty obviously wrong for subtraction, e.g. bit #1 is 1 from a `0-0`, with no borrow in because `1-1` in bit#0 cancels.  Also, `x-y` where `x>y` and both are positive can't cross zero.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the math by hand

setup both of them

```
  0110 0101 1101 0001
+ 0010 0011 0101 1001
=========================

                    1
  0110 0101 1101 0001
+ 1101 1100 1010 0110
=======================
```

start working both of them

```
              10 0010
  0110 0101 1101 0001
+ 0010 0011 0101 1001
=========================
              10 1010


                 1111
  0110 0101 1101 0001
+ 1101 1100 1010 0110
=======================
                 1000
```

and already they do not match

```
 11111 1011 0000 1111
  0110 0101 1101 0001
+ 1101 1100 1010 0110
=======================
  0100 0010 0111 1000
```

No borrow so borrow flag = 1, carry flag = 1 (inverse of borrow).  The msbit
in and out are the same so no signed overflow.  not zero so no zero flag.  And msbit is zero so negative flag is zero.